# Different numbers of both two sets of numbers

Tags: integers

If $A$ is the set containing the positive integer factors of $12$ and $B$ is the set containing the positive integer factors of $16$, how many different numbers are in both sets $A$ and $B$?

(Actually the answer says there are three different numbers but no matter how many times I count, I get that there are five. Why is the answer three?)

Comment: the intersection set has 3 elements:1,2,4.

Answer (score 1):

You misread "in both sets A and B" for "in either A or B".  The former means "in $A\cap B$", while the latter means "in $A \cup B$".  Besides you didn't request non-proper factors, so you have to count $1$, $12$ and $16$ as well.

So we have :
\begin{gather}
A = \{1,2,3,4,6,12\},\\
B = \{1,2,4,8,16\},\\
A\cap B = \{1,2,4\}.\\
\end{gather}

Comment: Geez I totally misunderstood the question. Thanks a lot!